# Update Cell using column and row using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to do a forEach on the objects in "result" below, lookup up the cell value in the "sumActual" sheet by "category" and "startofDate", then sum the two values and set the new summed value back to the cell in "sumActual".

For example in the sample sheet I'd expect the following in the sample sheet below.

B3: 100  (90 + 10)

C3: 100 (80 + 20)

B4: 1600  (1500 + 100)

C4: 266  (66 + 200)

I'm just not sure how to find the cell value by where the "category" and "startofDate" interesct.

Thanks in advance for any support.

```
{ result: 
 [ { category: 'Credit Card Fees',
   month: 'January',
   year: 2021,
   amount: 90,
   startofMonth: '01/01/2021' },
 { category: 'Credit Card Fees',
   month: 'February',
   year: 2021,
   amount: 80,
   startofMonth: '02/01/2021' },
 { category: 'Processing',
   month: 'January',
   year: 2021,
   amount: 1500,
   startofMonth: '01/01/2021' },
 { category: 'Processing',
   month: 'February',
   year: 2021,
   amount: 66,
   startofMonth: '02/01/2021' } ] }
```

Sample Sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17SId7mIzO3hVOC36Nq40O0bjPS5YfGOX4wsMU1NlbCU/edit?usp=sharing

```js
function sumActual () {
  const _ = LodashGS.load()
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js').getContentText())

  const transactions = getTransactions()
  // console.log({ transactions })

  const filterProcessedTransactions = _.filter(transactions, (o) => {
    return !moment(o.Processed).isValid()
  })
  // console.log({ filterProcessedTransactions })

  // Group By Category
  const grouped = _.groupBy(filterProcessedTransactions, (o) => {
    return [o.Category, o.Year, o.Month]
  })
  // console.log({ grouped })

  // sum amount
  const result = _.map(grouped, function (value, key) {

    const d = value[0].Month + '/1/' + value[0].Year
    const startOf = moment(d).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    const valid = moment(startOf).isValid()
    // console.log({ d, startOf, valid })

    return {
      category: value[0].Category,
      month: value[0].Month,
      year: value[0].Year,
      amount: _.reduce(value, function (total, o) {
        return total + o.Amount
      }, 0),
      startofMonth: startOf
    }
  })
  console.log({ result })

  // forEach, index and match where category, month, year match
}
```

Before Screenshot

[image]

After Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). Show your current script and research.

Comment: What do you mean by intersect?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. For example, about `B3: 100 (90 + 10)`, you want to put `90 + 30` to the cells "B3:100"? And, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I cannot find `startofDate`. I apologize for this. So, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect as the image?

Comment: Let me clarify.  The cell B3 should have the value 100 is the sum of the current value in B3 ( 10 ) plus the first object in result ( 90 ).  The idea is to use "category" and "startofDate" from the result data to look up the value where column A category matches and row 1 matches the startofDate from result.

Do the screenshots help?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Unfortunately, I have to apologize for my poor understanding. I cannot still understand your question. For example, in your sample input, the cell "B4" is changed from `100` to `180`. I cannot understand the logic for this. Can I ask you about the detailed logic for achieving your goal?

Comment: Sure thing.  The code above creates "result" from the transaction sheet, basically summing amount by category, month and year.  We'd then like to use result to lookup the cell where "category" and "startofMonth" from result match column A ( category ) and row 1 ( date ) in sheet sumActual.  Add "amount" from result to the value in the matching cell on sumActual and update the cell in sumActual. For example category: 'Credit Card Fees', startofMonth: '01/01/2021', amount: '90' would be added to B3 because category 'Credit Card Fees' matches and so does startofMonth '1/1/2021'.  Thus 90+10 = 100

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand the logic of the cell "B3". But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In my previous comment, I asked about the cell "B4". Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the logic for achieving the cell "B4". Why the value is from `100` to `180` for the cell "B4"? Can I ask you about the detailed logic for achieving your goal?

Comment: Completely my fault.  In mistyped the information, I've updated the post and screen shots.  Is that clearer now?  Sorry to waste your time with the error on my part.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your replying, I proposed a sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Using the value in your question, you want to convert from your upper image to your bottom image using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // This value is from your question.
  const { result } = {
    result:
      [{
        category: 'Credit Card Fees',
        month: 'January',
        year: 2021,
        amount: 90,
        startofMonth: '01/01/2021'
      },
      {
        category: 'Credit Card Fees',
        month: 'February',
        year: 2021,
        amount: 80,
        startofMonth: '02/01/2021'
      },
      {
        category: 'Processing',
        month: 'January',
        year: 2021,
        amount: 1500,
        startofMonth: '01/01/2021'
      },
      {
        category: 'Processing',
        month: 'February',
        year: 2021,
        amount: 66,
        startofMonth: '02/01/2021'
      }]
  };

  const obj = result.reduce((o, { category, amount, startofMonth }) => (o[startofMonth + category] = amount, o), {});
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sumActual");
  const [[, ...header], , ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const res = values.map(([h, ...v]) => v.map((f, j) => {
    const key = Utilities.formatDate(header[j], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy") + h;
    return obj[key] ? obj[key] + f : f;
  }));
  sheet.getRange(3, 2, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, the cells of sheet "sumActual" is updated using the value in your question. The goal in the bottom image in your question can be achieved from the upper image.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your sample image. So when your actual situation is different from it, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: This is great.  I'm going to continue working with it and trying to better understand exactly how it is working.  Thank you very much and again sorry for my mistake earlier.

Comment: @JAK Thank you for replying. It's no problem. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.